# Freeform 4 sends empty emails

Tags: add-on, email, solspace-freeform, solspace

I am currently using freeform version 4.0.6 in EE version 2.5.1

Some of the emails that were send are completely empty (no message body)

Am I the only one that is having this problem? Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: I'd reinstall FreeForm and triple check settings. You have field set up for the message and it matches? Are these entries going into FreeForm itself? You are probably better searching over at the Solspace forums ( http://www.solspace.com/forums/viewforum/10/) for specific their software.. I have had a quick look but couldn't find anything.

Comment: What does the content of your notification template look like? Are you using non-required fields in it, which means they could be empty? More details please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I updated Freeform to 4.0.8 which solved the problem.

In v4.0.6 something was wrong with the attachments that should be mailed.